# How do i retrieve timestamp from the firebase database

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was testing out to display a timestamp in my app from the firebase database. I was successful in generating a timestamp in the database as a double, but how do I retrieve it from there.
Also, how will the double be converted in to the normal date format once I load it from the database?

[image: my firebase database under users node]

Comment: You get it like any other Data in a Document? Its seconds passed since 1970 if i remember right, you can get it into a normal format with endless options, plain javascript, a time library, basicly you can write yourself a 4 line function in any language that makes it to a normal time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert the value from the database back to an `NSDate`:

```
NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: value/1000)
```

The `/1000` is neede, since `NSDate` expects the value in seconds, while you've stored the value in milliseconds.

Comment: Yes, but how do I get it from the database? Normally I use `setValuesForKeys` with a dictionary. I have a `class` with four properties, three `String?`s and one for the date. Should it be Double? or what?

Answer (score 1):

Use this extension to contain your transformations for `DataSnapshot`. In your case, the timestamp being in milliseconds needs dividing by 1000 to convert it into seconds.

```
extension DataSnapshot {
    var doubleValue: Double? { return value as? Double }
    var dateValue: Date? {
        return doubleValue.flatMap {
            Date(timeIntervalSince1970: $0 / 1000)
        }
    }
}
```

That way you can reuse them like so:

```
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    if let dateJoined = snapshot.child("dateJoined").dateValue {
        print(dateJoined)
    }
})
```